# Update the weight of a quote item

Tags: magento, cart, quote

I would like to update the weight of my quote item when I add a product in my cart on magento.

I tried this code:

```
public function checkoutCartProductAddAfter(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
   $event = $observer->getEvent();
   $quote_item = $event->getQuoteItem();
   $myWeight = ($quote_item->getWeight()/100)*$number;
   $quote_item->setWeight($myWeight);
   $quote_item->save();
}
```

But it's not working. I updated the price of the quote item in the
same function and it works.

Why doesn't my new weight apply?

Comment: Where does `$number` come from?

Comment: It's an integer take from a custom option but I know it's working cause I can display it. And if at the end of this function I echo getWeight(); I have myWeight (the correct value that I want to set) but if I take a look in my database: in the table "sales_flat_quote_item" it's the old weight that is save.

Comment: Why are you modifying the weight of the quoted item and not the product?

Comment: Because the weight of the product depends of a custom option fullfield by the customer on the product page: the customer give the height and the width of the product so the weight can be different for a same product.

Comment: It's not certain but I think you don't need `$quote_item->save();` because it is not used in Magento's native modules when setting the quote item attributes.

Comment: @vicch that all depends. If setWeight doesn't contain a save method then he may need to leave it in there.

Comment: how did you check that weight parameter was not set?

Comment: The weight is not apply to my cart because I have set a table rates and the shipping price tell me that it base on the original weight. Plus in my database I can't see the result of my setWeight.

Answer (score 3):

Use **sales_quote_item_set_product** event. This event is called on every request, after the Quote Item sets its product.
This is how you can change price and weight to custom values.

```
/*
 * Called on every request, updates item after loaded from session
 */
public function updateItem(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) 
{
    $item = $observer->getQuoteItem();
    if ($item->getParentItem()) {
        $item = $item->getParentItem();
    }

    // set price
    $item->setCustomPrice($customPrice);
    $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($customPrice);
    $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);

    // set weight
    $item->setWeight($customWeight);
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: When adding to cart, the weight does not seem to persist on the quote item. Inside my observer's `setWeight()` method, I added a logfile to simply log the quote item's weight. If I use `tail -f mylog.log` when adding to cart, it will correctly log the custom weight, but then the observer method is triggered a second time and the weight is then set to zero.

Comment: Derp, nevermind. I was basing the weight calc on some values set dynamically on the product. Since these values are never *saved* to the product, they would not persist after the first request. I saved them to the quote item instead (where I have an additional column already added).

Answer (score 1):

You need to save the quote or the cart not the quote item.
Try:

```
$quote_item->getQuote()->save();
```

or

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->save();
```

Comment: I have quickly try this and the result is the same, it doesn't change the weight at the checkout step. I will try until it works but somebody know witch value is use in the database to display the weight of the cart ?

Answer (score 1):

You are observing the right event

```
checkout_cart_product_add_after
```

No need to do this, you can remove this from your function

```
$quote_item->save();
```

but add this

```
$quote_item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
```

Now your function should read as

```
public function checkoutCartProductAddAfter(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{  
   $event = $observer->getEvent();
   $quote_item = $event->getQuoteItem();
   $myWeight = ($quote_item->getWeight()/100)*$number;

   $quote_item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);

   $quote_item->setWeight($myWeight);
}
```

The main thing that need to be done so that it does not write the original product weight to the table `sales_flat_quote_item` is to copy the `item.php` file from `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote` to `app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote` and Remove the following line (v1.9 CE) line # 390

```
->setWeight($this->getProduct()->getWeight())
```

Now it should work like a charm. Tried and tested

Comment: just FYI to anyone looking at the answer above, it works a treat. There is a typo - the file to edit and move to you local folder is /app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item.php

Answer (score 0):

you can try my code here. in sidebar.phtml

```
<?php
$items = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()
    ->getItemsCollection()->getItems();
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$total_weight = 0;
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $product = $item->getProduct();
    $qty = $item->getQty();
    $weight = $item->getWeight();
    if ($product->isConfigurable()) {
        $total_weight += ($weight * ($qty - 1));
    } else {
        $total_weight += ($weight * $qty);
    };
}
?>


<div><strong>Total Weight</strong></div>
</div><strong><?php echo $total_weight;?> KG</strong></div>
```

Comment: some explanation is required here if you got the problem reason, that why it is not working,what should he do with it,what changes are necessary.

Comment: This answer is just getting a value to display on the front-end. Values are never set on the quote for later retrieval. @aditcov did you even read the question?